# jQuery dropdown menu doesn't work how it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

So I tried to make a mobile menu and everything went perfectly fine, but when I click it it sends me to the top of the page instead of dropping down the menu. The CDN is linked properly (checked that with jQuery alert) so it's anchor tags fault or the jQuery code. Can you guys check it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#i-nav').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 320px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.testnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.testnav ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
.testnav ul li a {
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #626262;
}
#home:hover,
#menu2:hover,
#menu3:hover,
#menu4:hover,
#menu5:hover {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #b0b0b0;
}
#home:hover {
  background-color: rgba(223, 187, 66, 0.65);
}
#menu2:hover {
  background-color: rgba(196, 52, 52, 0.65);
}
#menu3:hover {
  background-color: rgba(80, 139, 97, 0.65);
}
#menu4:hover {
  background-color: rgba(89, 148, 160, 0.65);
}
#menu5:hover {
  background-color: rgba(87, 95, 189, 0.65);
}
#i-nav {
  float: left;
  z-index: 101;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.floatright-wrapper {
  float: right;
}
.testnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .floatright-wrapper {
    float: none;
  }
  .testnav ul {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .testnav ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .testnav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    outline: solid white 1px;
  }
  #logo {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #i-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #logo {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 27px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testnav" id="menu">
  <img src="css/images/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <a href="#" id="i-nav"><i class="fa fa-bars icon-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <div class="floatright-wrapper">
        <li><a href="#" target="_top" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="#text-boxes" id="menu2">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="picture-boxes-section" id="menu3">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="menu4">Menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="menu5">Menu5</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding a `return false` after the toggle. It is taking you to the top of the page because you are clicking a link. you need to stop the default action that a link causes.

Comment: Okay, It doesn't send me to top anymore, but it still doesn't toggle class show. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I have updated my thought on the problem. see my answer below.

Comment: you're hiding the `UL` in this media query `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) `, see if you need it or not, but that one is overriding your other rule

Answer (score 1):

The page is jumping to the top because when you are clicking the link it thinks that is the action you want to take. In order to prevent that try to edit your function like I have below. The `.preventDefault` function tells the browser that you do not want it to attempt to go to a different page like an anchor tag normally would.

```
$('#i-nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul').toggleClass('show');
});
```

EDIT

The reason your menu is not showing is because you are adding the `show` class to every ul that is on the page. Try to be specific and like `$('.test-nav ul').toggleClass('show');`

If you are still not seeing the menu, this is most likely because the previous css with `display: none` is overwriting your show class's `display: block` you can either resolve this by changing it to `display: block !important` or you can be explicit and give the `ul` a class or an `id`, then use that in your jQuery.

Here is an example of what I am talking about. If you have a couple of nested divs like so:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

With css like so:

```
.first .second {
    display: none;
}

.second {
    display: block;
}
```

The first one will always overwrite the second.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple thing need to added in your code and it will start working good . Just add !important to your class  .show . Check my Code for reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#i-nav').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 320px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.testnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.testnav ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
.testnav ul li a {
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #626262;
}
#home:hover,
#menu2:hover,
#menu3:hover,
#menu4:hover,
#menu5:hover {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #b0b0b0;
}
#home:hover {
  background-color: rgba(223, 187, 66, 0.65);
}
#menu2:hover {
  background-color: rgba(196, 52, 52, 0.65);
}
#menu3:hover {
  background-color: rgba(80, 139, 97, 0.65);
}
#menu4:hover {
  background-color: rgba(89, 148, 160, 0.65);
}
#menu5:hover {
  background-color: rgba(87, 95, 189, 0.65);
}
#i-nav {
  float: left;
  z-index: 101;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.floatright-wrapper {
  float: right;
}
.testnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .floatright-wrapper {
    float: none;
  }
  .testnav ul {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .testnav ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .testnav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    outline: solid white 1px;
  }
  #logo {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #i-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #logo {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 27px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testnav" id="menu">
  <img src="css/images/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <a href="#" id="i-nav"><i class="fa fa-bars icon-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <div class="floatright-wrapper">
        <li><a href="#" target="_top" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="#text-boxes" id="menu2">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="picture-boxes-section" id="menu3">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="menu4">Menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="menu5">Menu5</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```